# How can I simulate a palm mute effect in Reason?

Tags: reason

I would like to simulate a palm mute on synthesized guitars in Reason. I'm not after too much realism, just the basic effect.

Listening to some palm muting in metal, etc, I believe that a low pass filter would get me the frequency range, but how can I implement the percussive element into it?

Hope I worded it correctly and thanks for any replies :)

Comment: I don't have the answer, but I recently looked at a preset for my amp sim which simulated an electrified acoustic. It had problems, but it was fairly convincing and highly percussive. It was a long chain of EQs and out-of sync reverbs with tons of compression. Most of the mid-range was killed and some pretty aggressive boost of the highs, over and over again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can first try if a compressor with ≈ 400 ms attack, 30 ms decay, and rather violent threshold/ratio (something like -40 dB and ≥8:1) settings does the trick. If not, try a more conventional compressor setting (if the synthesized guitar has little dynamic range, that may not even be necessary) and put an expander/noise gate after it, which triggers only the note plucks. Fast attack and ≈ 400 ms decay.

If neither of these works satisfyingly, you will need to resort to specialized envelope tools, or to using a proper palm mute sound in the first place.

Note that, for a distorted sound, all tweaks can only work properly if you apply them *before* the distortion. Once the signal has passed the amp, it will be alnost impossible to do anything about the playing technique characteristics.